# blender not rendering last frame

Tags: rendering, animation, osx

When I render animations, it renders very fast. But I use MPEG-4 as the output and it doesn't render the last frame! The MP4 Never appeared. I had to use my SCREEN RECORDER to record the animation.
Specs:
M1 Air
M1 GPU
M1 CPU
8GB RAM
I hate my life

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It may be this issue: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/263568/image-strip-rendered-to-video-is-missing-half-of-its-frames-throughout-the-anima